# getJSON autocomplete & post?

Tags: jquery, post, autocomplete, getjson

using this to get data for a jquery ui autocomplete function but really want to send it as post. Otherwise it all works fine...

```
$.getJSON( "/youradmin_v2/scripts/php/process.php",{ 
term: extractLast( request.term ), func: 'autoCompleteMenu', query : 'GROUP BY contentType'}, 
response );
```

i've tried this;

```
$.post(url, dataToBeSent, function(data, textStatus) {
  //data contains the JSON object
  //textStatus contains the status: success, error, etc
}, "json");
```

but this messes up the autocomplete as the "json" replaces the response.

here's the current working autocomplete with the getJSON.
http://pastebin.com/hmMswasS

any help appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Whenever the built-in jquery $.post doesn't work for me, I go back and use the low-level $.ajax method. Try something like this:

```
<script>
  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/youradmin_v2/scripts/php/process.php',
    data: dataToBeSent,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data) {
      // handle response here
      // log(data);
    }
  });
</script>
```

Also, make sure you are returning proper JSON, i.e.

```
<?php
  json_encode($data_array);
?>
```

Comment: this works fine and can see the data getting returned. I just can't get the autocomplete to pick it up! Its somink to do with the getJSONs' ',response );' as that works but not sure how to replicate that part of it with ajax or post functions?  Tried;  success: function(data) { response = data;   } etc but no joy...

Comment: Daniel, go to this page and copy the js code into one of your files:
[plugins.js](https://github.com/paulirish/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/js/plugins.js)

Now in your response handler, call
`log(data);`

The returned json will show up in your log (make sure to use FF or chrome). You'll be able to see what exactly is coming in and help you to debug.

Answer (score 0):

Are your headers set in your php file to be `application/json`?

Comment: hey mazlix, no - its purely a php file for all the functions of my site.  Could i put that in a function? How would that affect the code above? Or the other function in the process.php file?

Comment: You just need to add `header('Content-type: application/json');` before you echo any code from that php function.... So if a part of your function is like `echo $data` just put the `header('Content-type: application/json');` right before that. I ussually put it at the top of all functions that are supposed to output JSON

Answer (score 0):

As per [this nice resource](http://davidwalsh.name/php-header-mime), you should only need to add this to the PHP file that serves your JSON response:

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
```